# Identify this ladybug-like insect, with yellow eyes and cream spots

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I have spotted this cream spotted ladybird like insect on my terrace. I live in Hyderabad, India and it's rare to see such an insect here. I have tried using image searches but haven't found any good matches. The underbelly is brown with some spots of yellow at the side. It is approximately 1-1.25cm in length. It's very hot around here generally but today is a cool day (30 deg C) and lightly sunny.

[image]

Comment: Excellent photo. That's a basil plant, no? Can you [edit] to add your approximate location in the world to aid in identification.

Comment: Thanks. That's a mint plant, commonly called pudina here. Location is Hyderabad, India.

Comment: Could it be Clinteria? https://indiabiodiversity.org/group/beetles_of_india/observation/show/17244829

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think (without any expertise in this area, so take with a grain of salt), that this is a beetle in the genus *[Clinteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinteria)*. This is a genus of beetles found in Asia and are relatively common.

Specifically I think this is *Clinteria klugi*, which has large pale yellow to red spots on the elytra and broad similarly coloured bands of the edge of the pronatum.

Lots of good photos can be found on [INaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/497921-Clinteria-klugi/browse_photos).

Incidentally, I think you might be confusing the bands on the pronatum for its eyes. The pronatum is kind of like a shield for the thorax, and in the case of this beetle, the head too. The eyes will be dark (as is needed to absorb visible light) and on the head, which is tucked under the pronatum.

Comment: Solved. The pictures match exactly what I had seen. Also check https://sar.fld.czu.cz/cache/article-data/SaR/Published_volumes/2020-1/115-132_jakl_2.pdf for more details about the beetle.